# Getting rid of the stench

Tags: cleaning, smell

I recently cleaned my dogs kennel. My girlfriend has been putting her puppy in with my older dog.  The kennel was thoroughly dirty.  Much urine and fecal matter on the concrete. I used a solution of MR. Clean antibacterial and white vinegar to clean and try and deodorize the concrete.  Now there is a tremendously strong rotten egg smell in my garage. Any ideas how to get rid of this stench?

Comment: Bleach. The rotten eggs smell is hydrogen sulfide which will react to gjve non-smelly product with bleach.

Comment: A house air ozonizer might help as well.

Comment: So long as you don't mind some permanently discolored concrete, @Waylander , is right on target. Don't bother playing around with deoderizers and such and just destroy the scent-causing stuff at the source with copious amounts of bleach. Of course you'll want to dilute it a bit and be careful of splattering onto skin and eyes.

Comment: Not a good idea to put vinegar on concrete. The vinegar etches the concrete and makes the surface more porous.

Answer (score 3):

It's probably a sulfide that's causing the stench.  If you have no luck with bleach, try hydrogen peroxide (3% to 6% is fine), which will oxidise the sulfur, and the products should be significantly less volatile.  It's the same thing that you'd do for a skunk spray.